# PL/pgSQL: Add static column to query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(a integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF newset AS

$BODY$
declare 
    x int;
begin

  FOREACH x IN ARRAY $1 
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM  func1(x); 
  END LOOP;

return;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

`func2` simply append all rows from all calls to `func1`. if first call to `func1` gave 2 rows and second call gave 3 rows, `func2` will return in total 5 rows (the rows themselves).

`func1` returns a schema of 3 columns so currently `func2` return same schema.

I want to change `func2` so it will return 4 columns. the 3 from `func1` and another column which contains the value of `x`.

for example:
calling `func2(ARRAY[500,200])`
and assume `func1(500)` return 2 rows and `func1(200)` return 3 rows.
I will get:

```
first  second third forth
a         b     c     500
d         e     f     500
g         h     i     200
j         k     l     200
m         n     o     200
```

I created a `newset2` which is `newset` with another column of int for func2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(a integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF newset2 AS
```

How do I add the desired column to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just return the extra column:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT *, x FROM  func1(x);
```

Comment: Can I order it by `x`? if i add `Order by` it doesn't work. it order specific call to `func1` instead of the whole total rows.

Comment: Your `func2` returns multiple times. In order to sort effectively, you could insert the various rowsets from `func1` into a temporary table and return that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be substantially **more efficient** with a plain `SELECT` query using `unnest()` a `LATERAL` join. Applying any sort order is simpler, too.

```
SELECT f.*, x
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[500,200]) x, func1(x) f  -- implicit LATERAL join
ORDER  BY x;
```

That's all, including the additionally requested sort order.
It's a drop-in replacement for your `SELECT * FROM func2(ARRAY[500,200])`, no `func2()` needed.

You *can* still wrap this into a function, of course. I suggest a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(a integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF newset AS
$func$
 SELECT f.*, x
 FROM   unnest(ARRAY[500,200]) x, func1(x) f
 ORDER  BY x; 
$func$  LANGUAGE sql
```

The row type `newset` has to be pre-defined somehow.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)